# Nextcloud Online Acocunt?

Tags: pantheon

Are there any plans in adding support for Nextcloud as online account? And/or what's the current state? How to help?

Would love to be able to sync contacts, calendars, tasks and files via Nextcloud by simply configuring an online account in Pantheon.

Thinking of something similar to GNOME online accounts:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23449/gnome-3-gnome-control-center-empty).

Elementary OS has the Gnome Control Center installed, but it's kind of hidden. You can try to open it from the command line with `gnome-control-center` but it's blank. I first tried installing Gnome Online Accounts with this:

```
sudo apt install gnome-online-accounts
```

That didn't resolve the situation. Then I found the solution I've linked to:

> Essentially the gnome control center only works when the desktop environment is Gnome. The command provided above sets the current environment to Gnome then opens the gnome-control-center inside of that environment. Allowing it to load properly.

So it'll work if you run this:

```
env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME gnome-control-center
```

Comment: While this is possible atm, **I don't recommend running gnome-online-accounts without actually running Gnome as [it is not officially supported and can break at any time](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-control-center/issues/248#note_481676).** Said that, this is unfortunately not a solution. FWIW: Luckily the priorities @elementaryOS seem to head into a similar direction. From what I've heard, further development for the Pantheon Online Account feature should play a major role for the upcoming 5.1 Release. Thingers crossed!

Comment: Thanks Marco, this is a good point. I'm impatient and I want to be able to backup to my Nextcloud server using Déja Dup. Right now this is a "good enough" solution for me. I can also keep an eye on my backups and check if anything happens to break.

However I agree that this shouldn't be used for anything mission-critical as it were.

Comment: @MarcoBetschart you are right but I'm now running this working and without any problems for half a year now. I can only recommend it! Also great answer!

Comment: @PhilRoggenbuck there's a open bounty for adding Nextcloud support to the elementary online-accounts here: https://www.bountysource.com/issues/44030100-add-nextcloud-provider-file 
I'll plan to tackle full native Nextcloud integration in elementary over the next months. See the elementary project over here for updates:
https://github.com/orgs/elementary/projects/63

Comment: @MarcoBetschart sounds great!